# C++ stl pointer based containers wrapper

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, containers, wrapper

I'm writing a program in which I manage tree and nodes (DAG).

Nodes are represented with a `class MCModule`.

```
class MCModule
{
...
};

typedef boost::shared_ptr<MCModule> MCModule_sp;
typedef MCModule * MCModule_p;
```

I have different kind of containers.

For example, in my class Node, the child nodes are managed with shared pointers.

```
std::list<shared_ptr<Node>> childs;
```

The parent nodes are manages within raw pointers:

```
std::list<Node *> parents;
```

I may also have a vector of nodes pointer in another class though.

All those containers store "pointers" of the class Module within shared_ptr or raw pointers.

Whatever the type of container, I need to perform some identical tasks: searching nodes based on its name, based on its id, based on

I started to write the follwing template class:

```
template<typename _ListT, typename _ElemT>
class ModuleListWrapper
{
public:
    explicit ModuleListWrapper(_ListT& lst) 
        : m_lst(lst){}

    /*! Indicates whether the \a module was found in the list or not
     *  \return true if the \a module was found, otherwise return false
     */
    inline bool find(const MCModule_sp& module) {
         return (std::find_if(m_lst.begin(), 
                              m_lst.end(),  
                              compare_with(module->getName()) ) != m_lst.end() );
    }

    inline _ElemT find(const std::string& name) {
        _ListT::iterator it = std::find_if(m_lst.begin(), m_lst.end(),  compare_with(name));
        return ( it != m_lst.end() ) ? (*it) : NullPtrT;
    }

// ... much more accessors ...


    /*! Overloads the -> operator to facilitate the access to the inner class.
        \return a pointer to the inner \a _ListT object
     */
    inline _ListT * operator->() const { return &m_lst; }

    /*! Gets a reference to the inner \a _ListT object
     */
    inline _ListT& get() const { return m_lst; }

private:
    _ListT& m_lst;
};

typedef ModuleListWrapper<ModuleList_shareptr, Module_shareptr> ModuleListWrapper_shareptr;
typedef ModuleListWrapper<ModuleList_rawptr, Module_p> ModuleListWrapper_rawptr;
typedef ModuleListWrapper<ModuleVector_rawptr, Module_p> ModuleListWrapper_rawptr;
```

The purpose of this class is to provide an interface to perform actions whatever the underlying container. 
Of course the container must "contain" pointer of the exepected type.

Do you think it is an acceptable solution or is it totally useless ?
Sure it is not perfect, but maybe better than inheriting from a std::list or std::vector... ?

Any critic, opinion and suggestion is welcome.

Comment: "Any critic, opinion and suggestion is welcome." Sounds more like a question for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). If you don't get much attention here at SO, try asking it there.

Comment: It seems you are mixing `shared_ptr` with raw pointers within your application, which is bad. If an object is pointed by both a raw pointer and a `shared_ptr`, you might get in trouble when the `shared_ptr` will delete your object

Comment: I would use weak pointer for parents.

Comment: N.B. Maybe you should point out when using raw pointers only as non-owning pointers.

Comment: Indeed, Im' using raw pointers "only" for non-owning purposes.